# Can we convert Jmeter Scripts to Neoload Scripts?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, neoload

We have scripts created is Jmeter and is there any direct/indirect way to convert them to Neoload scripts

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try to replay your JMeter scripts through NeoLoad proxy but you will be losing all the logic around the HTTP requests.
It would be much easier to directly use a software centered around JMeter like OctoPerf

Comment: Is there an option to convert Jmeter Script to Neoload Script in Software / website like Octoperf, I saw an option to convert from Loadrunner Scripts to Jmeter Scripts.

If so, please share me the link to do the same or download in case if there is an Application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to.  You can run your Jmeter scripts in Neoload, inherit the monitoring, analysis and reporting capabilities that are so weak in Jmeter as to require other tools to complete the set.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-create your existing JMeter scripts in Neoload.